# How to query first letter of each words consecutively in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to get the result of matched first letter of each words consecutively in sqlite.

For example I have data as following:

> - That Lucky Old Sun
> - Today My Life Begins

When I type `tl`, I want `That Lucky Old Sun` as the only result. I have done this command:

```
select * from table_name where column_name LIKE 't% l%'
```

but both data come out as the result.

Anyone can advise me how to done this query? Thanks!

Comment: your query seems ok. What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry. Edited my post

Comment: This wont do consecutive, but might work for any two words as long as they are in order: where column_name LIKE 't%' and column_name LIKE   '% l%'

Comment: I tried your query but still both data come out as result :(

Answer (score 2):

you can try using this

```
select * from table_name where column_name LIKE 't% l%' AND NOT LIKE 't% % l%'
```

Comment: Works like charm! I will accept this answer after some testing :)

Comment: yes .. please test with long sentences also .. I just thought about your given example

Comment: Hi StinePike, the query should be ok, but then when it comes to longer sentence, the chain will be like this 'where column_name LIKE 'a% b% m% q% k%' AND column_name NOT LIKE 'a% % b%'AND column_name NOT LIKE '%b% % m%'AND column_name NOT LIKE '%m% % q%'AND column_name NOT LIKE '%q% % k%'' Take a note, starts from second chain, the 'LIKE' must have '%' in front. That is the result as far as I have tested.

Comment: Oh btw, my query doesn't work with if there are some words with same initial :(

Comment: I give up StinePike! So I will process to get the initial of each word when inserting the sentence to sqlite and put it to other column which I will query in later :D